# Star Trek TNG TV episodes on DVD/Netflix different from network/cable telecast?

Tags: distribution, alternate-version, star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

Are DVD versions of TV episodes usually different than the TV broadcast version?

I was watching the ST:TNG series finale "All Good Things" on Netflix the other night.  I noticed, there was a difference in the scene where Picard is on the USS Pasteur with Dr. Crusher/Picard as the captain and they are asking/coercing Worf for permission to cross thru.

The difference between the TV episode and the Netflix version is Netflix had extra dialogue (I won't paraphrase/quote the dialogue, unless people want me to :) ).

Why does Netflix and presumably the DVD have this extra footage but the TV broadcast (as far as I can remember) did not?  Is this common for all TV shows?  I think I read something regarding Friends episodes being SHORTER on Netflix than its tv broadcast counterpart but I'd need to find that article.

Comment: Where were you watching originally? Some countries censored parts of several episodes.

Comment: Aired episodes may be "edited for time and content" and so may not be as originally aired...

Comment: @Catija, I was watching in the US both times, although, the first time I saw it on tv, it was on syndication like 10 yrs ago?  I know I've seen this episode a few more times on re-runs in subsequent years.

Comment: Syndicated shows are much more likely to be edited for time as CGCampbell mentioned.

Comment: Syndicated shows must allow more commercials per hour than broadcast shows.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, I agree with the commercials explanation but several other episodes I've seen for ST:TNG on Netflix vs. what I remember from tv, it doesn't appear like there's anything new added to other episodes on Netflix.  However, two things just dawned on me that 1) since this was the last episode of the series, they might have added this extra dialogue and put it in the DVD, vs. time restrictions on network/cable tv.  Also, 2) I didn't see the original broadcast in 1994 so my observation might not be 100% valid

Comment: Right: my claim is not that something was added for DVD/Netflix.  Instead, something was subtracted from the broadcast version to make the syndicated version.  And the original (broadcast) version is on DVD/Netflix.

Comment: Also remember that TNG dates to an era when show length was longer than current standards. They're even [speeding up](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/cable-networks-are-speeding-up-tv-shows-to-cram-in-ads/) shows!

Comment: @BCdotWEB, what do you mean shows were longer?  do you mean 1 hr shows back then were for example, 50 min long with 10 min of commercials whereas the shows now are closer to 42 min long with 18 min of commercials?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, nm, I read the link you provided.  Boooo fat cats adding more commercials and cutting our shows short

Comment: Just more info I found, wikipedia says the original took 105 min (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29). If we do the math, that's ~52 min for the show if it's split into 2 parts. Nowadays, I notice 1 hr shows are allotted ~43 min running time, as @BCdotWEB alludes to and thus probably why I noticed the additional dialogue from Netflix/DVD.  Thanks for everyone's answer to my question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, DVD versions of shows can often differ--sometimes drastically--from the original broadcast version, as can syndicated broadcasts.  Whether they'll include additional material or exclude original material all depends.

Most often, material is cut simply for time on broadcast.  In syndication runs, more ad revenue may need to be generated, so more time is cut, or the running time compressed (footage can be speeded up; sometimes inadvertently if video was crossing standards, since NTSC is 30 fps, and PAL is 25 fps).  In addition, sometimes content may have been censored by a network but added back in for a "director's cut" version (e.g., Steven Moffatt's *Jekyll* had three different edits--with different footage/audio [the audio edits were mostly for language] between the original BBC airings, the US airings on BBC America, and the DVD sets).  Another possible cause for differences can be linked to licensing issues with DVDs: for example, *Keen Eddie* lost their rights to some of the music used on the tracks for braodcast, and so the DVD went out with different music choices on the audio tracks.

And do we even need to mention [the issues with the HD blu-ray version of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer?*](https://www.facebook.com/notes/buffy-the-vampire-slayer-hd-blu-ray/whats-wrong-with-buffys-hd/590282824407343)

Comment: The 80's cartoon Dungeons And Dragons immediately comes to mind.  Each DVD release is slightly different, mostly in regards to the music and audio effects.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, thx, I'll have to look into this show too, although, I don't know if I can get my hands on ALL the DVD releases  =(